# C# - How to load text from text file in a listbox into a richTextBox?

Tags: c#

Now solved. Thanks for your answers!

This is my code right now:

```
  //Listbox scripts is the name of my folder
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Listbox scripts"))
        {
            string file2 = file.Split('\\').Last();
            listBox1.Items.Add(file2);
        }
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("SetText", new object[]
        {
            File.ReadAllText(string.Format("./Listbox scripts/{0}", listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()))
        });
    }
```

I'm new to coding in C# and I have a textbox that has the names of text files in a directory and when I click on the text file in the listbox it's supposed to load the text from it into my textbox (named 'ScriptBox')

Here's my code:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            string User = System.Environment.MachineName;
        textBox1.Text = "{CONSOLE} Welcome to Linst, " + User + "!";
        directory = new DirectoryInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Scripts");
        files = directory.GetFiles("*.txt");
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(file.Name);
        }
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedFile = files[listBox1.SelectedIndex];

        ScriptBox.Text = File.ReadAllText(selectedFile.FullName); //these parts are the parts that dont work
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How exactly is this failing?  Is there an error?  Unexpected output?

Comment: Add a breakpoint in your SelectedIndexChanged() handler and make sure it is actually getting hit.  If not, then you need to wire up that event.  Also, was "ScriptBox" dragged to the form from the toolbox?...or was it declared in code?

Answer (score 2):

Add the below into your Form1.cs. What this is going to do is when a user clicks a listbox item, its going to call (raise an event) the "listBox1_MouseClick" method and set the text of the textbox to the text of the listbox item. I just quickly created an app and implemented the below and it works.

```
private void listBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = listBox1.Text;
}
```

And add the below to the Form1.Designer.cs where the rest of your list box properties are. The below is subscribing to an event, the listBox1_MouseClick method in Form1.cs,  so when a user clicks on a listbox item, the listBox1_MouseClick method is going to run.

```
 this.listBox1.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(this.listBox1_MouseClick);
```

I hope the above makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is nice, and perfect but it just need a little validation check in list index selection
Try thing in your listbox_selectedIndexChanged

```
 private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex!=-1)
        {
            FileInfo selectedFile = files[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
            ScriptBox.Text = File.ReadAllText(selectedFile.FullName);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually don't see a problem with your code, could it be a typo somewhere?
I did this and it worked for me:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\"))
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(file);
    }
}


private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        textBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this answer is old, and sorry about not responding, but your code really helped me.